# Jmeter: Request should be change as per previous response

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

```
{
    {"status": 
    {"id":2,}
}
```

Next service should be

```
{
    "Data":"ABC"
}
```

similarly :

```
set Data = "DEF" if Id = 2 , Data = "GHI" if id = 3
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor as a child of the request which produces this `status` JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def id = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..id').get(0).toString()
   switch (id) {
       case '2':
           vars.put('Data', 'DEF')
           break;
       case '3':
           vars.put('Data', 'GHI')
   }
   ```
3. Amend your HTTP Request sampler Body Data to look like:

   [image: JMeter JSON Body Data]
4. If `id` will be `2` - `Data` value will become `DEF`, if `id` will be `3` - `Data` will become `GHI`

References:

- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)